# Регистрация домена

Tags: домен

Допустим, я на reg.ru увидел освобождающийся домен, могу ли я подать заявку на его регистрацию у другого регистратора?

Comment: @LiveStreet, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Можете. Либо дожидаетесь, когда домен освободится полностью и регистрируете где хотите, либо если думаете, что его может занять кто-то еще, то пользуетесь аукционом, например, на nic.ru